# OpenCV Memory Leak on Android - Garbage collection not working?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, opencv, memory-leaks

I'm making a simple demo app that processes frames of video one by one, and noticed I was getting a memory leak.  Tracing it back - it seems that `Mat` objects created inside a function are not being garbage-collected when the function terminates.

The following Kotlin code reproduces the issue:

```
class MainActivity ...
    ...

    override fun onCameraFrame(inputFrame: CvCameraViewFrame): Mat {
        val rgbaMat: Mat = inputFrame.rgba()!!
        val lets_have_a_memory_leak = false
        if (lets_have_a_memory_leak) {
            val unused_leaker = Mat.zeros(rgbaMat.size(), rgbaMat.type())
        }
        return rgbaMat
    }
```

if `lets_have_a_memory_leak==false`, the memory stays nice and bounded:

[image]

.  But if it's `lets_have_a_memory_leak==true`, memory quickly gets eaten up until the app is killed
[image]

For now I know I can solve this by keeping pre-allocated arrays for internal methods as class members, but in general it would be good to understand why garbage collection is not working as it should (it is expected to work, right?)

**Edit** I just discovered that calling `unused_leaker.release()` stops the overflow.

Comment: It would help to know which version of OpenCV you are using. Also realize garbage collection is not a zero-cost operation, see: [Android Developer Site: Memory Management](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview#gc) so preallocation make sense if you are trying for performant processing.

Comment: I'm using OpenCV 3.4.3.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/8683

Comment: Just confirming that this leak also happens on OpenCV 4.5.5.  Looks like the workaround solution is to manually call `Mat.release()` on any `Mat` object that is no longer needed - or reuse that array for future computations.  That is painful - it seems we basically need to do manual memory management, and experience memory leaks by default if we fail to do so.

Comment: @Peter do you know if in more recent versions the memory leak issue was fixed?

Comment: I don't - I gave up and started using Tensorflow-lite instead.